# Redirect with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

JQUERY

```
$('#myform').submit(function() 
{
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: 'checkit.php',
            data: 
            {
                usernameuser: $("#usernameuser").val(),
                passworduser: $("#passworduser").val()
            },
            success: function(html)
            {
                $(".gonewrong").html(""); 
                $(".gonewrong").show();
                $(".gonewrong").append(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

LOGIN FORM

```
            <form name="loginform" action="checkit.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="myform">  
                <table class="logintable">
                <tr class="logintr"><td class="mylabel">Username </td><td class="myinputfield"><input type="text" name="usernameuser" id="usernameuser"/></td></tr>
                <tr class="logintr"><td class="mylabel">Password </td><td class="myinputfield"><input type="password" name="passworduser" id="passworduser"/></td></tr>
                <tr class="logintrbutton"><td class="mylabel">&nbsp; </td><td class="mybutton"><input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="loginbutton" id="loginuser"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="gonewrong" colspan="3"></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

CHECKIT.PHP

```
if ($numUsers>0) 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: good.php");
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Incorrect username/password';
}
```

If the login is wrong everything works fine, the message error is displayed in the right place but if the login was successful it doesn't redirect me to good.php in the address bar of the browser but i see that page (good.php) inside gonewrong.

I spent many hours on this and can't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to redirect backend app, where the ajax is call.
You should redirect the front-page, where the javascript is.

**PHP:** (backend app, can't redirect here)

```
if ($numUsers>0) 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    //  header("Location: good.php"); - this not gonna work
    //  echo success instead:
    echo 'success';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Incorrect username/password';
}
```

**SCRIPT:** (front page, make redirection here)

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'checkit.php',
        data: 
        {
            usernameuser: $("#usernameuser").val(),
            passworduser: $("#passworduser").val()
        },
        success: function(status)
        {
           // check if successfully logged in:
           if('success'==status){
               //Success! user is logged in, need to redirect to good.php
               window.location.href='http://yoursite.com/good.php';
           }else{
               // Error! user is not logged in, show error message:
               $(".gonewrong").html(""); 
               $(".gonewrong").show();
               $(".gonewrong").append(status);
           }
        }
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: with your solution if the login wasn't successful it echos 'Incorrect username/password' in checkit.php and I want it in gonewrong td. It seems it skips the else statement.

Comment: It shouldn't. I have edited the answer 4 minutek after I wrote it. Tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried again now after having refreshed this page but it's so strange that it doesn't work

Comment: Try it now. I have added **e.preventDefault();** may this be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can't redirect in an AJAX response because the browser isn't navigating to a page.  Instead, examine the response in JavaScript and redirect from there.  Something like this:

```
if ($numUsers>0) 
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    echo 'success';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Incorrect username/password';
}
```

And in the JavaScript:

```
success: function(html)
{
    if (html == 'success') {
        window.location = 'good.php';
    } else {
        $(".gonewrong").html(""); 
        $(".gonewrong").show();
        $(".gonewrong").append(html);
    }
}
```

This is untested, you might want to debug the response and make sure it actually matches in a string comparison.  You could also take it a step further and respond with structured JSON data, which would make the JavaScript code a little less brittle.

But the main point is that server-initiated redirection only works on page navigations, not in API requests (AJAX).  In the case of using AJAX, the "application" is the client-side code and it needs to perform the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JavaScript to redirect?

```
$('#myform').submit(function() 
{
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: 'checkit.php',
            data: 
            {
                usernameuser: $("#usernameuser").val(),
                passworduser: $("#passworduser").val()
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                if (response.length > 0) {
                    $(".gonewrong").html(response); 
                    $(".gonewrong").show();
                }
                else {
                    location.href = 'good.php';  // redirect like this
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If the checkit.php has printed an error message, show it; otherwise, redirect.